# Webpack - Extend class - cannot read property prototype of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm migrating our Angular-CLI SystemJS project to the latest Webpack version.
I'm now running into the famous error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-getting-typeerror-cannot-read-property-prototype-of-undefined-in-__extends-

However, when I check the main.bundle.js; my base class is defined around line 40000, my child class at line 90000
Still I'm getting this error. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: can you log full error msg ? In which file does it occur ?

Comment: The child class is a service. It happens in my page component, that uses the child class, i.e. using dependency injection.

Comment: @candidJ when I look at the stack trace, it breaks at "... extends BaseClass".

Comment: I've fixed it in the end by starting over :)

Comment: @Boland could you please tell me where the error was? It's my third time starting over and still no solution

Comment: It has something to do with the barrels. I replaced some references to the barrel with a reference to the service directly. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It happened the same to me. In the end there were some circular dependencies in my code that system didn't complain about and webpack threw misleading messages.

Debugging did not work for me because I have so many modules and I lost trace. In the end instead of importing 'shared' or 'core' I broke it to shared/menu, shared/icon, core/session, and so on.

This broke all weird dependencies and started working quite fine

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when updating angular-cli. For me it was a dependency that failed. Try pausing on exceptions and dig deep into the exception and see if there is another exception with an exception message that is understandable. If you haven't tried that already.

Also make sure to overwrite everything when doing the ng init step to make sure that all config files are updated too.

Those problems were the ones I had when updating, hope it helps.

Comment: the trip results page == component, activityservice is an injectable that inherits from a base service. I'm not sure how to debug any further; it worked fine in System Config. I'm using barrels, I know it's advised against, but it was working fine and I've assured that I'm exporting in the right order. And it was working fine in system js...

Comment: Fixed it in the end by starting over :)

Comment: I use barrels for everything that is not injected. Can't get it to work for my services. Glad that it works now.